SVRG vs full gradient descent
Stochastic gradient descent allows us to avoid the computation of full gradients at the expense of introducing a noise floor to convergence. To decrease this noise floor, SGD requires a decrease in step size that loses linear convergence in the strongly convex case. SVRG (stochastic variance reduced gradient) allows us to return this linear convergence, but I am failing to see how this is computationally any better than just simple full gradient descent.
SVRG samples a full gradient at each iteration of an outer loop, and then performs inner loop steps of the form $w_t = w_{t-1} - \eta \left(\nabla f_{i_t}(w_{t-1})-\nabla f_{i_t}(\hat{w}) +  \nabla f(\hat{w})\right)$, where $\hat{w}$ is the current outer loop value. The idea is that we use the positive correlation between gradients to reduce variance in the estimator. In the strongly convex case, analysis in the paper then chooses as our next outer loop step a random one of these inner loop substeps. They then go on to present this as returning GD's linear convergence, but do so with convergence in the number of outer loop steps we have run. Each of these outer loop steps is computing a full gradient, so is this not doing full gradient descent plus some extra work with these inner loop steps - all to achieve the same convergence as GD?

It looks to me -and I'm not sure about this- that they essentially do a full descent calculation followed by m stochastic gradient descent steps, so there is still considerBle savings if m.is not small.

Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/648848/2921,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4929085/14578.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.  If you discover you have posted on the wrong site, please delete the copy on the original site before posting on a new site.

@D.W. yes, I was told in the comments there to post here - am aware cross posting is not normally a good idea.

@jbowman that's what I would expect, but their convergence bound in Theorem 1 of the paper is given in terms of the $s$ iterates as $\alpha^s$ - so it seems to me linear convergence is only achieved in terms of the outer loop iterations no?

I think the key is the middle paragraph on page 5; they show that (for $m$ large enough) they require $O(n)$ calculations to achieve a given accuracy vs $O(n^2)$ for "standard" SGD.  (I think it's really $O(nm)$, reading the previous stuff more closely.)  You're right, from the description of the algorithm it just seems like a constant in front of $n$ is changed by doing $m$ little steps in between each full calculation, but apparently not.  I'm traveling now so can't really analyze it in as much depth as I would like ATM.
